# Find all harmonic functions $u$ on $\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $u(z) \le x$

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

I'm new to complex analysis so I might be overlooking something. I'm thinking I could somehow use Liouville to make $u$ constant by taking $e^f$ where $f=u+iv$, with $v$ being the harmonic conjugate of $u$, but I seem to be stuck here. Another thing I tried was to use the Identity Theorem since taking $u(z)$ over purely imaginary numbers give a constant bound, but it says nothing about the actual sequence $u(iy)$. Any help?

Comment: *Hint:* $v(z) = x - u(z) $ is harmonic and $\ge 0$.

Comment: @MartinR I see, so now the idea of bounding $e^f$ works and we get that $u(z)-x$ is constant. Thank you!